# Speech Recognition for Julius using audio instead of Microphone

Tags: speech-recognition, microphone

I need to test [Julius](http://www.voxforge.org) Speech to Text conversion with some audio. moreover it would be possible to simulate noise over the audio.

is anyone aware of such a software?
Has anyone worked with Julius?
Any Comments on the library?

Answer (score 2):

Julius can recognize from many types of sources including raw files and pre-computed features. According to the [Julius book](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/julius/downloads/37581/Juliusbook-part-4.1.2-en.pdf) setting -input to raw will allow input of audio files.

There are databases and evaluations for speech recognition in noise for example the [Aurora framework](http://aurora.hsnr.de/index.html).

Comment: Could you, please, explain how to use a bigger dictionary than the one provided by default?

Comment: @Paul Dixon I'm trying to convert speech file(.wav file of monochannel, 16khz sample rate, 16bit) into text through julius, I used this command `julius -C my.jconf -input ~/Music/brian_mono_16000.wav`. and on terminal I got this `STAT: include config: my.jconf
ERROR: m_options: unknown speech input source "/home/gaian/Music/brian.wav"`. @Paul Dixon can you help me in this issue. Am I going in wrong direction?